# How to set the location response HTTP header in Express framework?

Tags: node.js, http-headers, express

How to set the response `Location` HTTP header in Express? I've tried this, but it's not working:

```js
  Controller.prototype.create = function(prop, res) {
    var inst = new this.model(prop);

    inst.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(500, err);
      }

      res.location = '/customers/' + inst._id;
      res.send(201, null);
    });
  };
```

This code is persisting a new document into MongoDB, and upon competition sets the location and send a `201` response. Got this response, no `Location` header is set:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 18 Feb 2013 19:08:41 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you're setting `res.location`. `res.location` is a function.

```
res.location('/customers/' + inst._id)
```

Answer (score 19):

The `res` object exposes `setHeader()`:

```
res.setHeader('Location', foo);
```

Try that instead of `res.location`.

Comment: It works. But why `res.location` (as per documentation http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.location) doesn't?

Comment: `location` is not a `property`, it's a method. See @Johnathan Ong's answer.

Comment: Specifically for location, you can use res.location(), as the other commenters said. But for other headers or custom headers, it's res.set(), not res.setHeader().

Answer (score -1):

an alternative way using core http libraries following code works:

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

  res.setHeader('Location', 'https://discord.gg/mSeCFujqqw');
  res.statusCode=301
  res.end()
    
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```